# Distance to the plane from the origin in terms of the Intercepts

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, vectors, euclidean-geometry, 3d

The intercept equation of a plane is

$$\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$$

where $x,y,z$ are the co-ordinates of an arbitrary point (say,$P$) on the plane and $a,b,c$ are the $x$-axis, $y$-axis and $z$-axis intercepts of the plane respectively

I was wondering the relation between the intercepts and the plane's distance from the origin. I tried in the following manner:

The general equation of the plane in Cartesian form is as follows:

$Ax+By+Cz+D=0$

Where $A,B,C$ are the direction ratios of the normal vector to the plane from the origin and $x,y,z$ are the same as above.

When we compare these two equations, we get

$A=\frac{1}{a}$, $B=\frac{1}{b}$ and $C=\frac{1}{c}$ and $D=-1$

Clearly, we can state that the vector, $$\frac{1}{a}î+\frac{1}{b}\hat{j}+\frac{1}{c}\hat{k}$$ is perpendicular to the plane from the origin

But if that is the case, then it must satisfy the identity

$\vec{r}.\hat{n}=d$

Where $\vec{r}$ is the position vector of the poin $P$ and $\hat{n}$ is the unit normal vector to the plane from the origin and $d$ is the distance to the plane from the origin

To convert $$\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$$ of the form $\vec{r}.\hat{n}=d$, we state

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}(\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$

Where the distance to the plane from the origin is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$

This is the general expression I have deduced of the distance of the plane. Is this correct? If not, please tell the correct relationship between the intercepts and the distance to the plane. I think I am mistaken in the first step itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a plane whose equation is
$$
Ax + By + Cz + D = 0, \tag{0}
$$
the distance of this plane from the point $P_0\left( x_0, y_0, z_0 \right)$ is
$$
\frac{ \left\lvert Ax_0 + By_0 + Cz_0 + D \right\rvert }{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2 }}. \tag{1}
$$
So if we put $x_0 = y_0 = z_0 = 0$ into (1), then the distance of the plane given by (0) from the origin is
$$
\frac{ \lvert D \rvert }{ \sqrt{ A^2 + B^2 + C^2 }}. \tag{2}. 
$$
Now the equation of your plane can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} + \frac{z}{c} -1 = 0. \tag{3} 
$$
Therefore the distance of the plane given by (3) from the origin is
$$
\frac{ \lvert -1 \rvert }{ \sqrt{ \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} + \frac{1}{c^2}  } } = \frac{ 1  }{ \sqrt{ \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} + \frac{1}{c^2}  } }. 
$$

Comment: You are right, I should have multiplied by $$\frac{ 1  }{ \sqrt{ \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} + \frac{1}{c^2}  } }$$ instead of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$

Answer (score 0):

It's less awkward if you get rid of fractions first, so multiply your original equation by $abc$. Then $A=bc,B=ac,C=ab,D=-abc$. The normal direction to the plane is $[A,B,C]$ so the parametric equation of the line through the origin and perpendicular to the plane is $$x=At,y=Bt,z=Ct.$$. This normal line intersects the plane for the value of $t$ given by $$A(At)+B(Bt)+C(Ct)+D=0,$$ so $$t=\frac{-D}{A^2+B^2=C^2}$$ Substituting this value of $t$ back into the parametric equation of the perpendicular line, we find that, to use old-fashioned language, that the foot of the perpendicular dropped from the origin to the plane is $$(\frac{-AD}{A^2+B^2=C^2},\frac{-BD}{A^2+B^2=C^2},\frac{-CD}{A^2+B^2=C^2})$$ We can easily find the distance from the origin to this point, and thence by substituting $A=bc,B=ac,C=ab,D=-abc$ obtain the desired formula.